# Future<void>.value();

Tags: flutter

Im having an issue while running the app. after initializing the app I couldnt properly see the screen at the same tiem there was an error shows which is **Future.value(); inside the feedback.dart. I have tried to catch any error which I have added but I couldnt find any.

I have seen many solution also tried but didnt worked out. Can I anyone please Let me know error which I showed below.

This is loginPage file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_app/bottombar/screenA.dart';


class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  static Future<User?>loginUsingEmailPassword({required String email, required String password, required BuildContext context}) async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user;
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      user = userCredential.user;

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if(e.code == "user not found"){
        print("No User found for that email");
      }
    }

    return user;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Hello world"),
      ),

      body: SizedBox(
        height: 400.0,
        child: Column(
          children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: emailController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: "Enter Username",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: passwordController,
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: "Enter Password",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async{
                    User? user = await loginUsingEmailPassword(email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text, context: context);
                     print(user);
                     if (user != null) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ScreenA()));
                     }
                }, 
                
                
                child: const Text("Login")),
             
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the main.dart file:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_app/loginpage.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future<FirebaseApp> _initializeFirebase() async {
    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = await Firebase.initializeApp();
    return firebaseApp;


  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeFirebase(),
        builder:  (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return const LoginPage();
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And my error is :

```
    context.findRenderObject()!.sendSemanticsEvent(const TapSemanticEvent());
    switch (_platform(context)) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
        return SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click);
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        return Future<void>.value();
    }
  }
```

Comment: The last part return Future<void>.value is my error.

Comment: What exactly does the error message say?
Can you post the whole method where context.findRenderObject... is used? What does the function signature look like?

Have you tried replacing the failing line by a simple "return;"?

Comment: What is the relevance of Kotlin here?

Comment: It used to say "Java" too, so I'm guessing the relevance is tag spam.

Comment: That is *not* your error.  That might be the code that *triggers* the error, but you haven't explained what the error is.  You also haven't shown context for that code (what is the function where that erroneous code resides?).  Really, you should try to provide a *minimal* example that other people can copy-and-paste to reproduce whatever problem you're encountering.